# Removing element of a Map inside a TreeMap

Tags: java, dictionary, treemap

I have this structure

```
TreeMap<String,Map<String,String>> map;
```

And i want to remove one of the key-value pair inside the Map found by a key.
I tried:

```
map.get(key).remove(key2);
```

But it throws a NullPointerException. 
To find the problem i tried:

```
Map<String,String> aux = map.get(key);
aux.remove(key2);
```

and saw that the map.get just returns null.

Any solution?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Well, if `map.get(key)` returns `null` that means there's no element for that key i  the outer map - it's as simple as that. If you think the element should be in the map we'd need to see some examples, i.e. which data you put into your map, what you use to look the elements up and whether or not you provided a custom comparator.

Comment: @Thomas It's **not** as simple as that. TreeMap supports null values, so null does not mean there is no mapping. There could be a mapping `foo -> null`

Comment: @Michael, well "no element for that key" isn't meant to say whether there's a mapping or not. I'd say `null` is _not_ an element, so even if `null` is mapped, there is no element for that key.

Comment: @Thomas Sorry, but you're objectively wrong. There **is** a functional difference between having a mapping to null and having no mapping. If I have a mapping to null, `containsValue(null)` will return true. If I don't, it won't. If I have a mapping to null, the `values()` collection will contain null. If I don't, it won't. If I have a mapping to null, `getKey` for the value's key will return true. If I don't, it will return false. This is basically precisely the reason `Optional` was added.

Comment: @Michael you're right about that, especially why `Optional` would help here. However, it depends on whether you consider `null` to be an element or not. In the OP's case it doesn't matter whether the key is mapped to `null` or the entry doesn't exist at all. In any case `map.get(key)` will return `null`. In that sense it's actually simple: there is no meaningful value/element for that key. Where it's not so simple is the why, i.e. is there no mapping or has `null` been put into the map - that's where `Optional` comes in handy (if you need to handle both cases differently).

Answer (score 0):

You could check if the outer key (in this case `key`) is present in the outer map and invoke the second `get` only if that is true.

```
Map<String,String> outerKey = map.get(key);
if(outerKey != null) {
    outerKey.remove(key2)
}
```

You get the `NullPointerException` because the key `key` is not present in the outer map (or is mapped to a null value), so `map.get(key)` returns null.